# Singleton values variables - domain undefined

Tags: prolog, clpfd, labeling

I've been trying to make a game. The game consistis in 9 pieces with dots in it. Each face of the piece has 0,1 or 2 dots.

```
[2,2,0,0,1,0]
```

This is a piece. This piece, look like this:

[image]

```
 [[2,2,0,0,1,0], %%peca1
           [2,1,0,0,1,1], %%peca2
           [2,0,0,0,1,1], %%peca3
           [2,0,0,0,0,0], %%peca4
           [1,0,0,0,1,0], %%peca5
           [1,0,0,0,0,0], %%peca6
           [1,0,0,0,0,0], %%peca7
           [0,0,0,0,1,0], %%peca8
           [0,0,0,0,0,0]]), %%peca9
```

These are all the pieces. (Front, right face, bacl, right, top, down)

[image]

The this is, when I run it, I get the message

```
[V2,V5,V7,V11,V12,V16,V17,V18,V19,V23,V26,V29,V31,V35,V41,V47,V53] - singleton variables
```

Any help or suggestions?

Best regards,

Luis Costa

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
dice:-

       Vars=[V1, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10, V11, V12,   V13,   V14, V15, V16, V17, V18,
  V19, V20, V21, V22, V23, V24, V25, V26, V27, V28, V29, V30, V31, V32, V33, V34, V35, V36,
  V37, V38, V39, V40, V41, V42, V43, V44, V45, V46, V47, V48, V49, V50, V51, V52, V53, V54],

    domain(Vars,1,9),




    table([
             [V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6], %%peca1
             [V7, V8, V9, V10, V11, V12], %%peca2
             [V13, V14, V15, V16, V17, V18], %%peca3
             [V19, V20, V21, V22, V23, V24], %%peca4
             [V25, V26, V27, V28, V29, V30], %%peca5
             [V31, V32, V33, V34, V35, V36], %%peca6
             [V37, V38, V39, V40, V41, V42], %%peca7
             [V43, V44, V45, V46, V47, V48], %%peca8
             [V49, V50, V51, V52, V53, V54]], %%peca9

          [[2,2,0,0,1,0], %%peca1
           [2,1,0,0,1,1], %%peca2
           [2,0,0,0,1,1], %%peca3
           [2,0,0,0,0,0], %%peca4
           [1,0,0,0,1,0], %%peca5
           [1,0,0,0,0,0], %%peca6
           [1,0,0,0,0,0], %%peca7
           [0,0,0,0,1,0], %%peca8
           [0,0,0,0,0,0]]), %%peca9
    labeling([],Vars).





noDotsFace:-
    sum([V2,V19, V7, V16, V31, V26],[V5, V23, V11, V53, V47, V41, V17, V35, V29, V18, V12], 7).
```

Comment: The message sums it up: Each of these variables occurs only *once* in your program. You can start such variables with an underscore to make clear that this is intended (as opposed to being a typo), i.e., write `_V2`, `_V5` etc. Alternatively, you can simply write `_` for each such variable.